# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm developing a mobile game in Unity. I installed Admob to add ads to my game and wrote the necessary code. I used the test IDs provided by Admob in the ID sections. The game runs smoothly in the Unity Editor. However, when I transferred it to my phone, test ads were not showing. Now, when I try to run the game, I can't even open it. It gives me the following error summary:

Text:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
 com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:
 *
 * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob -android-update-manifest 
 * to find your app ID.
 *
 * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:
 * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager -android-update-manifest.

 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7194)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6672)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6567)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:224)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 *******************************
 * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:
 *
 * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob -android-update-manifest
 * to find your app ID.
 *
 * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:
 * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager -android-update-manifest.
 *
 ******************

 at p0.e3.attachInfo(Unknown Source:99)
 at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:2)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7189)
 ... 10 more
```

What is the solution to this error?

Test ads appear in the Unity Editor but not on my Android device. While trying to solve this, I can no longer even open the game.

Comment: I can't do it. Because I'm experiencing the error on my own Android phone, and when I try to copy it, I can't select the words. Moreover, I have already provided the complete error text step by step through screenshots.

Comment: Thank you for your addition. I'm new to this platform, and I registered just to ask this question. If I made a mistake while asking the question, I apologize. I still haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in error message it says "Invalid application ID."

a) Are you add the app Id to your unity project ?
if you haven't done this, you shuld copy the app id from admob and add to your unity project. and here is the steps for this:

1. go to admob and choose your current project.
2. go to Application settings and in this tab you will find the Application ID. Copy this id.
3. Open your unity project. And go to Assets -> Google Mobile Ads -> Settings tab. In this tab you will find "Google Mobile Ads App Id". Paste the app id which you copied in step 2.
4. Now build your project again and check for result.

b) Maybe the app id that you add the project is wrong App Id. check for it.

Comment: I followed the steps, and yes, my game opened on my Android device. However, I encountered an issue. The test ads that worked seamlessly in the Unity Editor are not working on my Android device. I used the test AD IDs provided by AdMob while integrating the ads. How can I fix the issue of test ads not appearing on my Android device ?

Comment: I also encountered the same problem before. Here is the youtube video that fix your problem: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzktwmBmTQc&list=PLQTeePG9m5uvEPBDY-B5Ra4sSTjZIOFyJ&index=28&ab_channel=Slendgu) if its help you, Don't forget to mark my answer as correct and upvote my answer.

Comment: I had already watched the video you shared. I tried the solution mentioned in it, but it didn't work. The 2 lines him suggested to add were already present in the file. Thank you for your suggestion.